# 2D Dynamic Array, filled with Complex numbers

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays, complex-numbers

I am trying to initialize a 2D Dynamic array with complex doubles in it. I can't figure out what this error message is telling me to do and can't find it anywhere.

```
#include <complex.h> 
...
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    complex double **A;
    FILE *inputFile;
    int i;
    double numRow, numCol;

    inputFile = fopen( "input.txt", "r" );
    fscanf( inputFile, "%lf %lf", &numRow, &numCol );

    A = ((complex double)**)malloc( numRow * sizeof( (complex double)* ) );
    for( i = 0; i < numCol ; i++ ) {
        A[i] = ((complex double)*)malloc( NC * sizeof( (complex double) ) );


    for( i = 0; i < m; ++i ) {
        free( A[i] );
    }
    free( A );
```

The error I'm getting comes from the two lines which call malloc.

```
gewhpp.c:58:26: error: expected expression before â)â token
gewhpp.c:60:29: error: expected expression before â)â token
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try editing the lines with `complex double` to look like this:

```
A = (complex double**)malloc( numRow * sizeof(complex double* ));
```

You don't need to bracket around 'complex double' and then put the '*'

(You have some other errors with your braces, but I suppose that is because this is just snippets of code...)

Comment: The initial edit was correct. Thanks a lot, been stuck here for an hour...I'll accept the answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

```
A = ((complex double)**)malloc( numRow * sizeof( (complex double)* ) );
for( i = 0; i < numCol ; i++ ) {
    A[i] = ((complex double)*)malloc( NC * sizeof( (complex double) ) );
```

can be cleaned up to

```
A = malloc(numRow * sizeof *A);
if (A)
{
  for (i = 0; i < numCol; i++)
  {
    A[i] = malloc(NC * sizeof *A[i]);
    ...
```

Fewer chances for paren placement to bite you in the tuckus.

You don't need to cast the result of `malloc` in C (C++ is a different story), and you can apply the `sizeof` operator to an expression, not just a type name.  Since the type of `*A` is `complex double *`, the size of `*A` is the same as the size of `(complex double *)`.